# Conversion of String to particular class object

Tags: quartz-scheduler

There is a table in which a field of Name "Scheduler_Details" that having the values are:

[{"reportScheduledId":3980,"reportId":4353,"frequency":"Daily","dataSelection":"Report Date","scheduledTime":"15:52","contentType":"Run Now","userId":"5","userType":"","schedulerName":"Test7June4","isAutoSplited":false,"particularDay":"1","dataSelectionTypes":[],"runFlag":false,"ReportmailIds":"ram.newas@progenbusiness.com","isReportSchedule":true,"isExportReportSchedule":false,"schedulerLoadId":0,"fromOneview":false,"fromdsrbKpi":false,"forConditonalTest":false,"quickRefreshReport":false,"contextPath":"","advHtmlFileProps":"","filename":"","oneviewid":0,"oneviewMeasureOptions":[],"usrMesg":"","moduleType":"","isGO":false,"QueryScheduler":true,"queryScheduleNow":"00:00"}]

Problem is after getting from ResultSet in JAVA,it is type of "String" BUT
I need Object Type of ReportSchedule where

ReportSchedule is a class thats have setter and getter of all these values;

Answer (score 0):

Use a json serialiser (Newtonsoft.Json is the package most people use with C#)

```
string response = ".....";
var rs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportSchedule>(response);
```

Comment: Ah, no mention/tag of JAVA when I posted.  Still, isn't there a json library in JAVA?